# Función que ordena tabla no ordena correctamente

Tags: javascript, html

He estado haciendo una clasificación de la Liga 1|2|3, como objetivo personal para ir aprendiendo a utilizar HTML con JavaScript y CSS. He conseguido hacer una función que ordene los datos de la tabla según prioridad de los datos de cada equipo. Esta es la función:

```
function OrdenarTabla()
{
    var table, rows, switching, i, x, y, shouldSwitch;
    table = document.getElementById("liga123");
    switching = true;

    /* Bucle que continúa hasta que no se hace ningún cambio */
    while (switching)
    {
        /* Comenzar sin cambiar nada */
        switching = false;
        rows = table.rows;

        /* Ir por todas las filas menos la primera, que es la cabecera */
        for (i = 1; i < (rows.length - 1); i++)
        {
            /* No dejar hacer cambios */
            shouldSwitch = false;

            /* Coger los dos Puntos a comparar, el de la fila actual y el de la siguiente */
            x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[9];
            y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[9];

            /* Si los Puntos actuales son menores que los siguientes, cambiarlos. Si son iguales, bajar jerarquía */
            if (parseFloat(x.innerHTML) < parseFloat(y.innerHTML))
            {
                /* Cambiar, restaurar la jerarquía por Puntos y romper bucle */
                shouldSwitch = true;
                x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[9];
                y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[9];
                break;
            }
            if (parseFloat(x.innerHTML) == parseFloat(y.innerHTML))
            {
                /* Cambiamos la jerarquía a la columna de la Diferencia de Goles */
                x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[8];
                y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[8];

                if (parseFloat(x.innerHTML) < parseFloat(y.innerHTML))
                {
                    /* Cambiar, restaurar la jerarquía por Puntos y romper bucle */
                    shouldSwitch = true;
                    x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[9];
                    y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[9];
                    break;
                }
                if (parseFloat(x.innerHTML) == parseFloat(y.innerHTML))
                {
                    /* Cambiamos la jerarquía a la columna de los Goles a Favor */
                    x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[6];
                    y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[6];

                    if (parseFloat(x.innerHTML) < parseFloat(y.innerHTML))
                    {
                        /* Cambiar, restaurar la jerarquía por Puntos y romper bucle */
                        shouldSwitch = true;
                        x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[9];
                        y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[9];
                        break;
                    }
                    if (parseFloat(x.innerHTML) == parseFloat(y.innerHTML))
                    {
                        /* Cambiamos la jerarquía a la columna de las Victorias */
                        x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[3];
                        y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[3];

                        if (parseFloat(x.innerHTML) < parseFloat(y.innerHTML))
                        {
                            /* Cambiar, restaurar la jerarquía por Puntos y romper bucle */
                            shouldSwitch = true;
                            x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[9];
                            y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[9];
                            break;
                        }
                        if (parseFloat(x.innerHTML) == parseFloat(y.innerHTML))
                        {
                            /* Cambiamos la jerarquía a la columna de las Derrotas */
                            x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[5];
                            y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[5];

                            if (parseFloat(x.innerHTML) > parseFloat(y.innerHTML))
                            {
                                /* Cambiar, restaurar la jerarquía por Puntos y romper bucle */
                                shouldSwitch = true;
                                x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[9];
                                y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[9];
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (shouldSwitch)
        {
        /* Si se tiene que hacer un cambio, hacerlo e indicar que se ha hecho */
        rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 1], rows[i]);
        switching = true;
        }
    }
}
```

La tabla es la siguiente:

```
<div id="DIVclasificacion" align="center" style="display:block;">
        <table class="clasificacion_liga_123" id="liga123">
            <tr>
                <th>POS</th>
                <th>EQUIPO</th>
                <th>JUG</th>
                <th>VIC</th>
                <th>EMP</th>
                <th>DER</th>
                <th>GF</th>
                <th>GC</th>
                <th>DG</th>
                <th>PTS</th>
            </tr>
            <tr class="fila_ascenso">
                <td>1</td>  <!-- Posición -->
                <td class="nombre_equipo" id="equipo_1">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="img/teams/malaga.png" class="escudo_equipo">&nbsp; <span id="id_equipo_1">Málaga CF</span></td>
                <td id="jugados_1">11</td>  <!-- Partidos jugados -->
                <td id="victorias_1">8</td> <!-- Victorias -->
                <td id="empates_1">1</td>   <!-- Empates -->
                <td id="derrotas_1">2</td>  <!-- Derrotas -->
                <td><span type="text" id="golesFavor_1">14</span></td>  <!-- Goles a favor -->
                <td><span type="text" id="golesContra_1">6</span></td>  <!-- Goles en contra -->
                <td><span id="golesDiferencia_1">8</span></td>  <!-- Diferencia de goles -->
                <td class="puntos" id="puntos_1">25</td>    <!-- Puntos -->
            </tr>
            <tr class="fila_ascenso">
                <td>2</td>  <!-- Posición -->
                <td class="nombre_equipo" id="equipo_2">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="img/teams/granada.png" class="escudo_equipo">&nbsp; <span id="id_equipo_2">Granada CF</span></td>
                <td id="jugados_2">11</td>  <!-- Partidos jugados -->
                <td id="victorias_2">7</td> <!-- Victorias -->
                <td id="empates_2">2</td>   <!-- Empates -->
                <td id="derrotas_2">2</td>  <!-- Derrotas -->
                <td><span type="text" id="golesFavor_2">18</span></td>  <!-- Goles a favor -->
                <td><span type="text" id="golesContra_2">8</span></td>  <!-- Goles en contra -->
                <td><span id="golesDiferencia_2">10</span></td> <!-- Diferencia de goles -->
                <td class="puntos" id="puntos_2">25</td>    <!-- Puntos -->
            </tr>
            <tr class="fila_promocion">
                <td>3</td>  <!-- Posición -->
                <td class="nombre_equipo" id="equipo_3">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="img/teams/deportivo.png" class="escudo_equipo">&nbsp; <span id="id_equipo_3">Deportivo</span></td>
                <td id="jugados_3">11</td>  <!-- Partidos jugados -->
                <td id="victorias_3">6</td> <!-- Victorias -->
                <td id="empates_3">4</td>   <!-- Empates -->
                <td id="derrotas_3">1</td>  <!-- Derrotas -->
                <td><span type="text" id="golesFavor_3">18</span></td>  <!-- Goles a favor -->
                <td><span type="text" id="golesContra_3">8</span></td>  <!-- Goles en contra -->
                <td><span id="golesDiferencia_3">10</span></td> <!-- Diferencia de goles -->
                <td class="puntos" id="puntos_3">22</td>    <!-- Puntos -->
            </tr>
            <tr class="fila_promocion">
                <td>4</td>  <!-- Posición -->
                <td class="nombre_equipo" id="equipo_4">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="img/teams/alcorcon.png" class="escudo_equipo">&nbsp; <span id="id_equipo_4">Alcorcón</span></td>
                <td id="jugados_4">11</td>  <!-- Partidos jugados -->
                <td id="victorias_4">6</td> <!-- Victorias -->
                <td id="empates_4">3</td>   <!-- Empates -->
                <td id="derrotas_4">2</td>  <!-- Derrotas -->
                <td><span type="text" id="golesFavor_4">13</span></td>  <!-- Goles a favor -->
                <td><span type="text" id="golesContra_4">6</span></td>  <!-- Goles en contra -->
                <td><span id="golesDiferencia_4">7</span></td>  <!-- Diferencia de goles -->
                <td class="puntos" id="puntos_4">21</td>    <!-- Puntos -->
            </tr>
            <tr class="fila_promocion">
                <td>5</td>  <!-- Posición -->
                <td class="nombre_equipo" id="equipo_5">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="img/teams/palmas.png" class="escudo_equipo">&nbsp; <span id="id_equipo_5">UD Las Palmas</span></td>
                <td id="jugados_5">11</td>  <!-- Partidos jugados -->
                <td id="victorias_5">5</td> <!-- Victorias -->
                <td id="empates_5">4</td>   <!-- Empates -->
                <td id="derrotas_5">2</td>  <!-- Derrotas -->
                <td><span type="text" id="golesFavor_5">16</span></td>  <!-- Goles a favor -->
                <td><span type="text" id="golesContra_5">9</span></td>  <!-- Goles en contra -->
                <td><span id="golesDiferencia_5">7</span></td>  <!-- Diferencia de goles -->
                <td class="puntos" id="puntos_5">19</td>    <!-- Puntos -->
            </tr>
            <tr class="fila_promocion">
                <td>6</td>  <!-- Posición -->
                <td class="nombre_equipo" id="equipo_6">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="img/teams/albacete.png" class="escudo_equipo">&nbsp; <span id="id_equipo_6">Albacete</span></td>
                <td id="jugados_6">11</td>  <!-- Partidos jugados -->
                <td id="victorias_6">4</td> <!-- Victorias -->
                <td id="empates_6">5</td>   <!-- Empates -->
                <td id="derrotas_6">2</td>  <!-- Derrotas -->
                <td><span type="text" id="golesFavor_6">17</span></td>  <!-- Goles a favor -->
                <td><span type="text" id="golesContra_6">12</span></td> <!-- Goles en contra -->
                <td><span id="golesDiferencia_6">5</span></td>  <!-- Diferencia de goles -->
                <td class="puntos" id="puntos_6">17</td>    <!-- Puntos -->
            </tr>
            <tr class="fila_azul">
                <td>7</td>  <!-- Posición -->
                <td class="nombre_equipo" id="equipo_7">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="img/teams/mallorca.png" class="escudo_equipo">&nbsp; <span id="id_equipo_7">RCD Mallorca</span></td>
                <td id="jugados_7">11</td>  <!-- Partidos jugados -->
                <td id="victorias_7">4</td> <!-- Victorias -->
                <td id="empates_7">4</td>   <!-- Empates -->
                <td id="derrotas_7">3</td>  <!-- Derrotas -->
                <td><span type="text" id="golesFavor_7">13</span></td>  <!-- Goles a favor -->
                <td><span type="text" id="golesContra_7">11</span></td> <!-- Goles en contra -->
                <td><span id="golesDiferencia_7">2</span></td>  <!-- Diferencia de goles -->
                <td class="puntos" id="puntos_7">16</td>    <!-- Puntos -->
            </tr>
            <tr class="fila_blanca">
                <td>8</td>  <!-- Posición -->
                <td class="nombre_equipo" id="equipo_8">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="img/teams/oviedo.png" class="escudo_equipo">&nbsp; <span id="id_equipo_8">Oviedo</span></td>
                <td id="jugados_8">11</td>  <!-- Partidos jugados -->
                <td id="victorias_8">4</td> <!-- Victorias -->
                <td id="empates_8">3</td>   <!-- Empates -->
                <td id="derrotas_8">4</td>  <!-- Derrotas -->
                <td><span type="text" id="golesFavor_8">13</span></td>  <!-- Goles a favor -->
                <td><span type="text" id="golesContra_8">15</span></td> <!-- Goles en contra -->
                <td><span id="golesDiferencia_8">-2</span></td> <!-- Diferencia de goles -->
                <td class="puntos" id="puntos_8">15</td>    <!-- Puntos -->
            </tr>
            <tr class="fila_azul">
                <td>9</td>  <!-- Posición -->
                <td class="nombre_equipo" id="equipo_9">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="img/teams/almeria.png" class="escudo_equipo">&nbsp; <span id="id_equipo_9">Almería</span></td>
                <td id="jugados_9">11</td>  <!-- Partidos jugados -->
                <td id="victorias_9">4</td> <!-- Victorias -->
                <td id="empates_9">2</td>   <!-- Empates -->
                <td id="derrotas_9">5</td>  <!-- Derrotas -->
                <td><span type="text" id="golesFavor_9">12</span></td>  <!-- Goles a favor -->
                <td><span type="text" id="golesContra_9">10</span></td> <!-- Goles en contra -->
                <td><span id="golesDiferencia_9">2</span></td>  <!-- Diferencia de goles -->
                <td class="puntos" id="puntos_9">14</td>    <!-- Puntos -->
            </tr>
            <tr class="fila_blanca">
                <td>10</td> <!-- Posición -->
                <td class="nombre_equipo" id="equipo_10">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="img/teams/sporting.png" class="escudo_equipo">&nbsp; <span id="id_equipo_10">Real Sporting</span></td>
                <td id="jugados_10">11</td> <!-- Partidos jugados -->
                <td id="victorias_10">3</td>    <!-- Victorias -->
                <td id="empates_10">5</td>  <!-- Empates -->
                <td id="derrotas_10">3</td> <!-- Derrotas -->
                <td><span type="text" id="golesFavor_10">9</span></td>  <!-- Goles a favor -->
                <td><span type="text" id="golesContra_10">7</span></td> <!-- Goles en contra -->
                <td><span id="golesDiferencia_10">2</span></td> <!-- Diferencia de goles -->
                <td class="puntos" id="puntos_10">14</td>   <!-- Puntos -->
            </tr>
            <tr class="fila_azul">
                <td>11</td> <!-- Posición -->
                <td class="nombre_equipo" id="equipo_11">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="img/teams/elche.png" class="escudo_equipo">&nbsp; <span id="id_equipo_11">Elche CF</span></td>
                <td id="jugados_11">11</td> <!-- Partidos jugados -->
                <td id="victorias_11">3</td>    <!-- Victorias -->
                <td id="empates_11">5</td>  <!-- Empates -->
                <td id="derrotas_11">3</td> <!-- Derrotas -->
                <td><span type="text" id="golesFavor_11">11</span></td> <!-- Goles a favor -->
                <td><span type="text" id="golesContra_11">13</span></td>    <!-- Goles en contra -->
                <td><span id="golesDiferencia_11">-2</span></td>    <!-- Diferencia de goles -->
                <td class="puntos" id="puntos_11">14</td>   <!-- Puntos -->
            </tr>
            <tr class="fila_blanca">
                <td>12</td> <!-- Posición -->
                <td class="nombre_equipo" id="equipo_12">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="img/teams/osasuna.png" class="escudo_equipo">&nbsp; <span id="id_equipo_12">Osasuna</span></td>
                <td id="jugados_12">11</td> <!-- Partidos jugados -->
                <td id="victorias_12">3</td>    <!-- Victorias -->
                <td id="empates_12">4</td>  <!-- Empates -->
                <td id="derrotas_12">4</td> <!-- Derrotas -->
                <td><span type="text" id="golesFavor_12">11</span></td> <!-- Goles a favor -->
                <td><span type="text" id="golesContra_12">11</span></td>    <!-- Goles en contra -->
                <td><span id="golesDiferencia_12">0</span></td> <!-- Diferencia de goles -->
                <td class="puntos" id="puntos_12">13</td>   <!-- Puntos -->
            </tr>
            <tr class="fila_azul">
                <td>13</td> <!-- Posición -->
                <td class="nombre_equipo" id="equipo_13">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="img/teams/numancia.png" class="escudo_equipo">&nbsp; <span id="id_equipo_13">Numancia</span></td>
                <td id="jugados_13">11</td> <!-- Partidos jugados -->
                <td id="victorias_13">3</td>    <!-- Victorias -->
                <td id="empates_13">4</td>  <!-- Empates -->
                <td id="derrotas_13">4</td> <!-- Derrotas -->
                <td><span type="text" id="golesFavor_13">10</span></td> <!-- Goles a favor -->
                <td><span type="text" id="golesContra_13">15</span></td>    <!-- Goles en contra -->
                <td><span id="golesDiferencia_13">-5</span></td>    <!-- Diferencia de goles -->
                <td class="puntos" id="puntos_13">13</td>   <!-- Puntos -->
            </tr>
            <tr class="fila_blanca">
                <td>14</td> <!-- Posición -->
                <td class="nombre_equipo" id="equipo_14">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="img/teams/rayo.png" class="escudo_equipo">&nbsp; <span id="id_equipo_14">Rayo Majadahonda</span></td>
                <td id="jugados_14">11</td> <!-- Partidos jugados -->
                <td id="victorias_14">4</td>    <!-- Victorias -->
                <td id="empates_14">1</td>  <!-- Empates -->
                <td id="derrotas_14">6</td> <!-- Derrotas -->
                <td><span type="text" id="golesFavor_14">9</span></td>  <!-- Goles a favor -->
                <td><span type="text" id="golesContra_14">15</span></td>    <!-- Goles en contra -->
                <td><span id="golesDiferencia_14">-6</span></td>    <!-- Diferencia de goles -->
                <td class="puntos" id="puntos_14">13</td>   <!-- Puntos -->
            </tr>
            <tr class="fila_azul">
                <td>15</td> <!-- Posición -->
                <td class="nombre_equipo" id="equipo_15">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="img/teams/lugo.png" class="escudo_equipo">&nbsp; <span id="id_equipo_15">CD Lugo</span></td>
                <td id="jugados_15">11</td> <!-- Partidos jugados -->
                <td id="victorias_15">3</td>    <!-- Victorias -->
                <td id="empates_15">3</td>  <!-- Empates -->
                <td id="derrotas_15">5</td> <!-- Derrotas -->
                <td><span type="text" id="golesFavor_15">11</span></td> <!-- Goles a favor -->
                <td><span type="text" id="golesContra_15">13</span></td>    <!-- Goles en contra -->
                <td><span id="golesDiferencia_15">-2</span></td>    <!-- Diferencia de goles -->
                <td class="puntos" id="puntos_15">12</td>   <!-- Puntos -->
            </tr>
            <tr class="fila_blanca">
                <td>16</td> <!-- Posición -->
                <td class="nombre_equipo" id="equipo_16">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="img/teams/tenerife.png" class="escudo_equipo">&nbsp; <span id="id_equipo_16">Tenerife</span></td>
                <td id="jugados_16">11</td> <!-- Partidos jugados -->
                <td id="victorias_16">2</td>    <!-- Victorias -->
                <td id="empates_16">6</td>  <!-- Empates -->
                <td id="derrotas_16">3</td> <!-- Derrotas -->
                <td><span type="text" id="golesFavor_16">11</span></td> <!-- Goles a favor -->
                <td><span type="text" id="golesContra_16">14</span></td>    <!-- Goles en contra -->
                <td><span id="golesDiferencia_16">-3</span></td>    <!-- Diferencia de goles -->
                <td class="puntos" id="puntos_16">12</td>   <!-- Puntos -->
            </tr>
            <tr class="fila_azul">
                <td>17</td> <!-- Posición -->
                <td class="nombre_equipo" id="equipo_17">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="img/teams/reus.png" class="escudo_equipo">&nbsp; <span id="id_equipo_17">Reus Deportiu</span></td>
                <td id="jugados_17">11</td> <!-- Partidos jugados -->
                <td id="victorias_17">3</td>    <!-- Victorias -->
                <td id="empates_17">3</td>  <!-- Empates -->
                <td id="derrotas_17">5</td> <!-- Derrotas -->
                <td><span type="text" id="golesFavor_17">9</span></td>  <!-- Goles a favor -->
                <td><span type="text" id="golesContra_17">13</span></td>    <!-- Goles en contra -->
                <td><span id="golesDiferencia_17">-4</span></td>    <!-- Diferencia de goles -->
                <td class="puntos" id="puntos_17">12</td>   <!-- Puntos -->
            </tr>
            <tr class="fila_blanca">
                <td>18</td> <!-- Posición -->
                <td class="nombre_equipo" id="equipo_18">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="img/teams/zaragoza.png" class="escudo_equipo">&nbsp; <span id="id_equipo_18">Zaragoza</span></td>
                <td id="jugados_18">11</td> <!-- Partidos jugados -->
                <td id="victorias_18">2</td>    <!-- Victorias -->
                <td id="empates_18">5</td>  <!-- Empates -->
                <td id="derrotas_18">4</td> <!-- Derrotas -->
                <td><span type="text" id="golesFavor_18">12</span></td> <!-- Goles a favor -->
                <td><span type="text" id="golesContra_18">13</span></td>    <!-- Goles en contra -->
                <td><span id="golesDiferencia_18">-1</span></td>    <!-- Diferencia de goles -->
                <td class="puntos" id="puntos_18">11</td>   <!-- Puntos -->
            </tr>
            <tr class="fila_descenso">
                <td>19</td> <!-- Posición -->
                <td class="nombre_equipo" id="equipo_19">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="img/teams/cadiz.png" class="escudo_equipo">&nbsp; <span id="id_equipo_19">Cádiz</span></td>
                <td id="jugados_19">11</td> <!-- Partidos jugados -->
                <td id="victorias_19">2</td>    <!-- Victorias -->
                <td id="empates_19">5</td>  <!-- Empates -->
                <td id="derrotas_19">4</td> <!-- Derrotas -->
                <td><span type="text" id="golesFavor_19">8</span></td>  <!-- Goles a favor -->
                <td><span type="text" id="golesContra_19">11</span></td>    <!-- Goles en contra -->
                <td><span id="golesDiferencia_19">-3</span></td>    <!-- Diferencia de goles -->
                <td class="puntos" id="puntos_19">11</td>   <!-- Puntos -->
            </tr>
            <tr class="fila_descenso">
                <td>20</td> <!-- Posición -->
                <td class="nombre_equipo" id="equipo_20">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="img/teams/extremadura.png" class="escudo_equipo">&nbsp; <span id="id_equipo_20">Extremadura</span></td>
                <td id="jugados_20">11</td> <!-- Partidos jugados -->
                <td id="victorias_20">2</td>    <!-- Victorias -->
                <td id="empates_20">3</td>  <!-- Empates -->
                <td id="derrotas_20">6</td> <!-- Derrotas -->
                <td><span type="text" id="golesFavor_20">13</span></td> <!-- Goles a favor -->
                <td><span type="text" id="golesContra_20">17</span></td>    <!-- Goles en contra -->
                <td><span id="golesDiferencia_20">-4</span></td>    <!-- Diferencia de goles -->
                <td class="puntos" id="puntos_20">9</td>    <!-- Puntos -->
            </tr>
            <tr class="fila_descenso">
                <td>21</td> <!-- Posición -->
                <td class="nombre_equipo" id="equipo_21">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="img/teams/gimnastic.png" class="escudo_equipo">&nbsp; <span id="id_equipo_21">Nástic</span></td>
                <td id="jugados_21">11</td> <!-- Partidos jugados -->
                <td id="victorias_21">2</td>    <!-- Victorias -->
                <td id="empates_21">3</td>  <!-- Empates -->
                <td id="derrotas_21">6</td> <!-- Derrotas -->
                <td><span type="text" id="golesFavor_21">8</span></td>  <!-- Goles a favor -->
                <td><span type="text" id="golesContra_21">18</span></td>    <!-- Goles en contra -->
                <td><span id="golesDiferencia_21">-10</span></td>   <!-- Diferencia de goles -->
                <td class="puntos" id="puntos_21">9</td>    <!-- Puntos -->
            </tr>
            <tr class="fila_descenso">
                <td>22</td> <!-- Posición -->
                <td class="nombre_equipo" id="equipo_22">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="img/teams/cordoba.png" class="escudo_equipo">&nbsp; <span id="id_equipo_22">Córdoba</span></td>
                <td id="jugados_22">11</td> <!-- Partidos jugados -->
                <td id="victorias_22">1</td>    <!-- Victorias -->
                <td id="empates_22">5</td>  <!-- Empates -->
                <td id="derrotas_22">5</td> <!-- Derrotas -->
                <td><span type="text" id="golesFavor_22">11</span></td> <!-- Goles a favor -->
                <td><span type="text" id="golesContra_22">22</span></td>    <!-- Goles en contra -->
                <td><span id="golesDiferencia_22">-11</span></td>   <!-- Diferencia de goles -->
                <td class="puntos" id="puntos_22">8</td>    <!-- Puntos -->
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Por las pruebas que he hecho parece ser que la función recoge bien los datos de la tabla, pero no los ordena correctamente.
Se supone que debe hacer una pasada por todas las filas de la tabla, y si los puntos de la primera son menores que los de la segunda, cambiar las filas, y volver a empezar desde la primera fila de la tabla de nuevo (por si por ejemplo el equipo tiene que avanzar más de una posición). Si los puntos son iguales, debería pasar a ordenar en ese respectivo caso por la diferencia de goles. Si también son iguales, pasaría a ordenar según goles a favor, victorias y menos derrotas, en ese orden de jerarquía siguiendo el sistema que acabo de explicar.
El problema es que ejecuto la función cada vez que edito los valores de la tabla para probar su funcionamiento y no se ordena como debería. ¿Podríais decirme en qué he fallado? Puedo añadir más información si hace falta, pero creo que con esas 2 cosas debería ser suficiente

Comment: Te sugiero que conviertas la tabla en un json o si tienes los datos en un json lo ordenes que a mi parecer es fácil.

Comment: @DarwinZamora ¿Qué beneficios tendría convertir la tabla en un JSON? Nunca anduve con ninguno

Comment: Que es mucho menos código, por lo tanto es más fácil de mantener y además es más fácil ordenar los datos en el json ya que javascript tiene métodos que hacen esto.

Comment: @DarwinZamora Entonces en el contexto de mi tabla, debería hacer en un archivo de JSON una variable para cada equipo con los campos posición, archivo de imagen (para el escudo), nombre, jugados, victorias, empates, derrotas, goles a favor, goles en contra, diferencia de goles y puntos con sus respectivos valores, y luego "comunicarlo" con la tabla de la clasificación para que ésta muestre cada campo sacado del archivo JSON, ¿no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tal y como dice Darwin, lo ideal seria que tuvieras tu información en un JSON para que sea incluso mas fácil de controlar que directamente en el HTML. Te dejo un ejemplo:

```js
window.onload = function () {
    const theadTitles = [
        'POS',
        'EQUIPO',
        'JUG',
        'VIC',
        'EMP',
        'DER',
        'GF',
        'GC',
        'DG',
        'PTS'
    ];

    const teams = [
        { id: 1, teamName: 'Equipo 1', gamesPlayed: 11, victories: 8, ties: 1, loses: 3, goalsInFavor: 14, goalsInCounter: 6, goalsDiff: 8, points: 25},
        { id: 2, teamName: 'Equipo 2', gamesPlayed: 11, victories: 2, ties: 0, loses: 9, goalsInFavor: 14, goalsInCounter: 6, goalsDiff: 8, points: 22},
        { id: 3, teamName: 'Equipo 3', gamesPlayed: 11, victories: 3, ties: 1, loses: 7, goalsInFavor: 14, goalsInCounter: 6, goalsDiff: 8, points: 23},
        { id: 4, teamName: 'Equipo 4', gamesPlayed: 11, victories: 6, ties: 0, loses: 5, goalsInFavor: 14, goalsInCounter: 6, goalsDiff: 8, points: 27},
        { id: 5, teamName: 'Equipo 5', gamesPlayed: 11, victories: 5, ties: 1, loses: 6, goalsInFavor: 14, goalsInCounter: 6, goalsDiff: 8, points: 26},
        { id: 6, teamName: 'Equipo 6', gamesPlayed: 11, victories: 3, ties: 2, loses: 6, goalsInFavor: 14, goalsInCounter: 6, goalsDiff: 8, points: 24},
        { id: 7, teamName: 'Equipo 7', gamesPlayed: 11, victories: 4, ties: 1, loses: 6, goalsInFavor: 14, goalsInCounter: 6, goalsDiff: 8, points: 21},
    ];

    var theadTr = document.getElementById('thead_tr');
    var tbody = document.getElementById('tbody');

    for (let title of theadTitles) {
        let th = document.createElement('th');
        th.appendChild(document.createTextNode(title));
        theadTr.appendChild(th);
    }

    for (let team of teams) {
        var tr = document.createElement('tr');
        Object.values(team).forEach(function (value) {
            var td = document.createElement('td');
            td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(value));
            tr.appendChild(td);
        });
        tbody.appendChild(tr);
    }


};
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Dynamic table</title>
</head>
<body>
<table class="table" id="table">
    <thead id="thead">
    <tr id="thead_tr">

    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tbody">
    <tr id="tbody_tr">

    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ¿Sabes cómo podría meter el código HTML del escudo que utilizaba en la tabla del post original? Es para que aparezca el escudo al lado del nombre en la clasificación